# Can't find a reference to a class that is in the same namespace as the calling class

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have a C# class in Visual Studios2010 that is referencing a globals class in the same namespace. This project is in a solution with several other projects and will build on its own. When I try to build the entire solution it loses reference to the globals class in its own namespace. The weird thing about this is there is another class also using globals in the same namespace and it works just fine.

Things I have tried:

-Changing the framework to every possible option.

-Deleting the class completely cleaning rebuilding restarting my computer etc.

-Making the project the startup project

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated I’m chasing my tail at this point.

Comment: You say there are many projects. Do the projects that "work" feature a reference to the project containing the `Globals` class and those that don't work are missing this reference? Namespace sharing isn't enough for type discovery, you need to reference the relevant projects also for compile-time discovery.

Comment: The project is referencing 2 others in the solution and sees them just fine and I’m using using directives for those. The globals file I’m having issues with is actually in the project that won't build and is in the same namespace. Globals is just a name there isn't anything global about it. It has a few methods and constants that I use throughout the project which is why I named it that. Another class references it just fine and intellisense picks it up without a problem but for some reason it says it cannot be found when I build the solution.

Comment: Have you tried using fully qualified namespaces everywhere? Can you reproduce the problem in a short, self-contained example [http://sscce.org/] project?

Comment: I have tried using the fully qualified names. Recreating the issue would be hard it is a rather large project. The problem boils down to two classes in the same project and namespace can't see each other. I have recently tried creating the same class and naming it something else. It is now seeing the globals but keeps telling me that it can’t find the original file I deleted.

Comment: @user1483446 Can you post the code for these two classes? Just the class definition parts: `public class Globals { }` etc, not the main body. If they are in the same project, but not visible then I would either assume different namespaces or non-public accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is a syntax error. I had a similar error earlier today and solved it by, well, fixing said syntax error (specifically removed a rogue closing curly brace). How to test: syntax errors will not propagate above, so just write a method at the very beginning of the class which has trouble referencing the Globals class:

```
public void testGlobals()
{
    Globals testglobals = new Globals(); //or whatever other constructor
}
```

If it does (i.e. the the class name changes colors and no red squiggly line appears), start moving it down method by method until the class name goes all white (or black, if you're into that retina destroying color scheme) and you get the red squiggly line back. Then fix said syntax error.